# Creating apache alias without access to .conf file

Tags: php, apache, alias

I have a PHP application that is written in Zend Framework. The document root is appdir/public. In appdir I also have a directory called admin that hosts a wordpress website.  I would like to be able to map an alias to appdir/admin so that the wordpress website can be reached at website.com/admin.  Unfortunately, I do not have access to my apache conf files through my hosting provider.  Is it possible to map an alias without access to that? I was thinking in the .htaccess file but after extensive googling, that doesn't look possible either.  All help/suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

I have tried contacting my hosting provider and getting access to the apache conf file, but they wouldn't let me. (SiteGround)

I have tried using the .htaccess file.

Edit: Apache 2.4

Comment: Why not simply move the admin directory to appdir/public?

Comment: That's an option, I was just trying to keep all "code" out of the public directory.

Comment: If you make the folder visible on the web is it not a public folder? You expose the code anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can' use .htaccess to move current directory above **document root**.